# maybe type in haskell, and what is slash in my statement?

Tags: haskell

I have an example such as:

```
firstTop40 :: Maybe Int
firstTop40 = find (\x -> digitSum x == 40) [1..]
```

My question is why do I need "maybe" here in function prototype?

Second question is: Why would I need `\x` here?

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because this site is not suitable for the very first steps of learning a new programming language. There are many suitable Haskell tutorials available that will cover these basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `Maybe` because you aren't sure if you'll find what you're looking for, it's Haskell's way of saying: *"maybe you're getting a result, maybe not"*.

So say you have this:

```
find (\x -> x > 40) [1 .. 10]
```

It looks for the first number that is greater than 40, in a list that only goes to 10. what's it going to find? Nothing.

And that's exactly what it finds:

```
Prelude Data.List> find (\x -> x > 40) [1 .. 10]
Nothing
```

`Nothing` is one of the two possible outcomes of a `Maybe`, the other is `Just`.

Like if I changed `> 40` to `>= 5`, the result would be this:

```
Prelude Data.List> find (\x -> x >= 5) [1 .. 10]
Just 5
```

Then you might say *"well, why doesn't it just return 0 if it doesn't find anything?"*, that's because, what if 0 is one of the possible results of your search, would you want it to both mean "I found 0" and "I found nothing"? Of course not! That's why `Nothing` means you found nothing.

As for why you need to write `\x`, that's fairly simple too.

The example code you showed can also be written as such:

```
sumIs40 :: Int -> Bool
sumIs40 x = digitSum x == 40

firstTop40 :: Maybe Int
firstTop40 = find sumIs40 [1..]
```

But let's say you only use `sumIs40` once, and that's in that one spot in your code, so you replace `sumIs40` with a `\`, and change the `=` to a `->` and drop it in where the function would normally have been called.

This is called an `anonymous` function, or `lambda` function, and a little bit of Googling around will tell you more about them and how useful they are, but you can basically think of them as one-time functions without a name.

Actually, on a more advanced note: If you wanted to, you could leave the `\x ->` out completely like this:

```
Prelude Data.List> find (>= 5) [1 .. 10]
Just 5
```

You can read that as *"find anything greater-than-or-equal-to 5, in a list from 1 to 10"*, which then yields `Just 5`

The above example is possible because of something called `currying` and/or `partial application` which you can also read more about on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You need `maybe` because `find` returns a `Maybe`.  If it finds a value, say 10, it returns `Just 10` otherwise it returns `Nothing`.

The `\x -> digitSum x== 40` is a lambda expression, and `\x` is how you bind the variable.

Comment: @user2407038 Thanks for the edit.  I guess I was mixing my functional languages a bit.